# I've recently discovered DCT and I'm wondering how one would solve this limit :

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

The limit: $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  n\int_{2}^{e} [\ln(x)]^n \mathrm dx $$

The book from where I took this exercise offered these as possible results :

- $e$
- $0$
- $1$
- $\ln(2)$
- infinity

I was able to pinpoint the solution ($e$) by substituting $x=e^t$ and then building the integral from  $\ln(2)\le t\le1$, and in the end reaching to $2\le n\int_{2}^{e} [\ln(x)]^n \mathrm dx \le e$ . The only solution possible, considering the answers the book gave, was $e$.

The problem is, I still didn't solve the problem. I am still not sure how to reach the correct result so in my attempt to find a way, I discovered DCT. I tried to understand as much as I can but there are still a lot of empty gaps.

In order to use DCT, I tried bringing the $n$ inside the integral and then use the substitution $t=(\ln(x))^n$ which gives us $ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{(\ln(2))^n}^{1} t^\frac{1}{n} \mathrm dt $. Because the lower bound depends on $n$, I basically got stuck.

So with all of this said, is there a way to use DCT to solve this limit?

Comment: MathJax tip: use `\le,\ge,\lt,\gt` for inequality signs. Also use `\ln,\exp,\sin,` and so on - backslashes are your friend

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254006/evaluate-lim-n-to-inftyn-int-2e-ln-xndx).

Comment: Was $[\cdot]$ mean to be used as integer part or as a parenthesis?

Comment: Please, define acronyms. Otherwise you may lose a wide audience that is caught out of context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$*Too long for a comment. David's link gives you a good solution, I am just showing you your attempt would have also worked had you pursued it.*

Let: $$I_n:=\int_2^e\ln^n(x)\,\d x$$Let, as you suggested, $t=\ln^n(x)$. Then $t^{1/n}=\ln x$, $x=\exp(t^{1/n})$. Then: $$\frac{\d x}{\d t}=\exp(t^{1/n})\cdot\frac{1}{n}t^{-1+1/n}$$And we have: $$I_n=\frac{1}{n}\int_{\ln^n2}^1t\cdot\exp(t^{1/n})t^{-1+1/n}\,\d t=\frac{1}{n}\int_{\ln^n2}^1t^{1/n}\exp(t^{1/n})\,\d t$$You can apply the dominated convergence theorem by observing that:

- $|\ln2|\lt1\therefore\ln^n2\to0$ so integrating over $(0,1]$ will provide domination
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}t^{1/n}=1$ for all $t\gt0$ and on the interval $(0,1]$ this is a monotone increasing limit
- The function $t^{1/n}\exp(t^{1/n})$ is an increasing positive function

Then the integrand $t^{1/n}\exp(t^{1/n})\chi_{[\ln^n2,1]}$ is dominated by (*and converges pointwise to*) $1\exp(1)\chi_{(0,1]}=e\cdot\chi_{(0,1]}$, and you can finish from here. In fact this convergence is monotonic, so the monotone convergence theorem suffices.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Because of your answer, I was also able to find the mistake in my attempt. I appreciate your help !

Comment: @Doppler You're very welcome. I should add that my concluding remark was incomplete - the integrand is dominated by $e\cdot\chi_{(0,1]}$ **but crucially it also converges to** this function. Indeed, as the convergence is monotone increasing, you don't need DCT and only need the monotone convergence theorem which is more elementary